# MongoDB: Upon incomplete Mass delete, are the deleted values gone or they are rolled back as in a typical RDBMS Transaction?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

Ten transactions, MongoDB upon deletion|update messes up at (let's say) 5th one. Does Mongoose, then, delete the deleted ones or it rolls back since the actual "transaction" of "mass delete" did not successfully complete.

Comment: @Neil Lunn, it's not the same, there is a difference. The duplicate question was answered upon how to achieve that transaction especially with mongodb and not mongoose which is an ODM.

Comment: Nope. No difference at all. You are talking about "transactions" and MongoDB "does not have them". Mongoose is "client side software" and "not a datbase", which of course means "no transactions". So *"How to work around the lack of transactions..."* That's why you need to get reading.